# Outputting sequence in TensorFlow RNN

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I created a simple TensorFlow program that tries to predict the next character using the previous 3 characters in a body of text.

A single input could look like this:

```
np.array(['t','h','i'])
```

with the target about being

```
np.array(['s'])
```

I'm trying to expand this to output the next say 4 character rather than just the next character. To do this I tried feeding in a longer array to y

```
np.array(['s','','i'])
```

In addition to changing the y to

```
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, n_steps])
```

however, this yields the error:

> Rank mismatch: Rank of labels (received 2) should equal rank of logits
>   minus 1 (received 2).

Here's the full code

```
embedding_size=40
n_neurons = 200
n_output = vocab_size
learning_rate = 0.001

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, n_steps])
    y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None])
    seq_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

    # Let's set up the embedding converting words to vectors
    embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=[vocab_size, embedding_size], minval=-1, maxval=1))
    train_input = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, x)

    basic_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(num_units=n_neurons)
    outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, train_input, sequence_length=seq_length, dtype=tf.float32)

    logits = tf.layers.dense(states, units=vocab_size, activation=None)
    predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        labels=y,
        logits=logits)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)   

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for r in range(1000):
            x_batch, y_batch, seq_length_batch = input_fn()
            feed_dict = {x: x_batch, y: y_batch, seq_length: seq_length_batch}
            _, loss_out = sess.run([training_op, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
            if r % 1000 == 0:
                print("loss_out", loss_out)

        sample_text = "for th"
        sample_text_ids = np.expand_dims(np.array([w_to_id[c] for c in sample_text]+[0, 0], dtype=np.int32), 0)
        prediction_out = sess.run(predictions, feed_dict={x: sample_text_ids, seq_length: np.array([len(sample_text)])})
        print("Result:", id_to_w[np.argmax(prediction_out)])
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of many-to-many RNN, you should use `tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss` to calculate per time step loss. Your code should look like this:

```
...
logits = tf.layers.dense(states, units=vocab_size, activation=None)
weights = tf.sequence_mask(seq_length, n_steps)
xentropy = tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(logits, y, weights)
...
```

See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/sequence_loss) for more details on `tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss`.